# Is there one configure to config in env to migrate correctly when changing column's name within Alembic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I used alembic to migrate database in flask, it seems like alembic didn't give correct way to migrate data, it just created new column and removed old column, it caused that data may be dropped, here is the code.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run xxx python manage.py db migrate -m "change number into index"
```

**migrations/versions/xxx.py**

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('news', sa.Column('index', sa.Integer(), nullable=True))
    op.drop_column('news', 'number')
```

**migrations/env.py**

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = logging.getLogger('alembic.env')

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from flask import current_app
config.set_main_option(
    'sqlalchemy.url',
    str(current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.engine.url).replace('%', '%%'))
target_metadata = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True, compare_type=True
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    # this callback is used to prevent an auto-migration from being generated
    # when there are no changes to the schema
    # reference: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html
    def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
        if getattr(config.cmd_opts, 'autogenerate', False):
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                directives[:] = []
                logger.info('No changes in schema detected.')

    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            compare_type=True,
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Is there some configure to config in env.py to use correct method like `alter_column` instead of this way to migrate?

I just care specific configure instead of searching generalized configure to auto-correct miss.

Comment: I used docker to generate file above, that file is auto-generated, I don't want to change codes in it by hand, so I asked this question, if have to, I will change it.

Comment: You can adjust the `upgrade` method in the auto-generated file and use `alter_column` instead. And then run the migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `op.alter_column`:

```
op.alter_column('table_name', 'old_column', nullable=False, new_column_name='new_column')
```

Comment: Thank you, I will change file by hand finally if there is really no configure to config it.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect

Comment: I saw it, it said can't detect `Changes of column name`, I think I need to manual modifiy auto-generate file.